# Linear transformation of vector spaces over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, prime-numbers, linear-transformations, finite-fields

I have been trying to solve a query:

> For wich prime numbers $p$ is the map
> $$\varphi:\ \Bbb{F}_p^2\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_p^2:\ (x,y)\ \longmapsto\ (x^p,y^p),$$
> a linear transformation of vector spaces?

I started solving it with Fermat's Little Theorem and concluded that it is not only for the odd ones. Is it only for the even one, for all of them, or even for none of them?

Comment: What's Fp? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By Little Fermat $\phi$ is the identity mapping, so it is always a linear transformation because the identity mapping is.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to find the prime numbers $p$ for which the map
$$f:\ \Bbb{F}_p\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_p:\ x\ \longrightarrow\ x^p,$$
is $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear, as then it easily follows that your map is also linear. Clearly $f(0)=0$, and indeed Fermat's little theorem tells you that this is an $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear map for every prime number $p$.

If the prime number $p$ is replaced by a prime power $q$, the map is still a $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear. A little more work is required, but you can use the fact that $\Bbb{F}_q^{\times}$ is cyclic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess my last remark was a bit unclear; what I meant is that the map $f(x)=x^q$ is $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear on $\Bbb{F}_q$. ( as it is the identity)